# how to integrate package org.slf4j.logger and org.slf4j.loggerfactory in java?

Tags: java, slf4j

i am running java programs from commandline, no IDE like eclipse please tell me how to integrate these packages so that wont get the error package doesn't exist, please tell me the step by step procedure to do so